# Why file dialog box not opening?

Tags: javascript

I am using following code to open a file dialog box, but nothing happens on button click(). What's wrong?

```
<input id="btnBrowse" name="btnBrowse" type="button" value="Browse" onclick="document.execCommand('SaveAs');"/>
```

**Edited:**

Any other way to open such a dialog on other browsers as well?

Comment: look at this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833015/does-execcommand-saveas-work-in-firefox

Comment: Related SO post: [Javascript: document.execCommand cross-browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817441/javascript-document-execcommand-cross-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative. It's name is [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) and is a JQuery implementation.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, It will work only in IE. It is working on my IE 7 and not in FF.

Check this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536419%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[IT works in IE only !](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/169427-execcommand-saveas)