# execCommand for font-size causes problem in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jquery based rich text editor "lwRTE"

It works well in all ways except in changing fontsize

I traced the problem as follows:

when i change the font size the command and the argument is chosen correctly as "font size" and "[the font size in number Eg.6]"

now the **execCommand** is executed and **chrome executes it differently**.

firefox changes the selected text as

```
 <font size="6px">sample text</font>
```

chrome changes the selected text as

```
<span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-size: xx-large;">sample text</span>
```

this is what causes the problem. when i edit and save using Chrome, firefox seems to not understand the above way of formatting.

how do i make chrome also do the same? (i.e) insert font tag and insert crazy font sizes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817441/javascript-document-execcommand-cross-browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [compatibility charts for `execCommand`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html) at http://quirksmode.org.  [<strike>Internet Explorer doesn't support font-size changing at all</strike>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536991(v=VS.85).aspx), Opera and Firefox wrap the font tag and Safari/Chrome behave as you suggested.

You can't change this functionality, you would have to build an alternative that works with the current selection range to implement one x-browser compatible method.

Comment: thanks.. now restricted font size options to 6. If it goes beyond 7 chrome starts using webkit which creates problems