# How to hightlight the text of matched terms in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of Items and a search box. if search term entered into the search box the matched text should appear with bold letters in the list irrespective of the case(case insensitive). 
I have done up to some level but later i dont know how to do it, as i am new to the jquery.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
          src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".SearchElement").keyup(function(){
            keyword = $(".SearchElement").val();
            if(keyword.length>=3){
                 var content = $(".wrapperbox ul li").text();
                 test = content.match(/keyword/gi)
                 if(test){
                     //alert(test);
                 }
            }
          });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <label>SearchTerm:</label> <input type="text" 
        name="SearchBox" value="" class="SearchElement" />
    </form>
    <div class="wrapperbox">
        <ul>
            <li>TestString</li>
            <li>testString</li>
            <li>Kanigiri</li>
            <li>KANIGIRI</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i do that, any help will be greatly appriciated. Thank you

Comment: Take a look at my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505602/slow-highlighting-in-firefox/12505656#12505656).

Comment: Please provide a better title so that future searchers will be able to find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
          src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#SearchElement").keyup(function(){
            keyword = $("#SearchElement").val();
            if(keyword.length>=3){
                 $(".wrapperbox ul li").each(function(index) {
                      var content =  = $(this).text());
                      test = content.match(/keyword/gi);
                      if (test){
                           $(this).replaceWith( "<li><b>" + $(this).text() + "</b></li>" );
                      }                      
                 });

            }
          });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <label>SearchTerm:</label> <input type="text" 
        name="SearchBox" id="SearchBox" value="" class="SearchElement" />
    </form>
    <div class="wrapperbox">
        <ul>
            <li>TestString</li>
            <li>testString</li>
            <li>Kanigiri</li>
            <li>KANIGIRI</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

1. use an ID to reference your form input
2. use a each() loop
3. basically fiddle about and find replace within that loop (I did a weak version - untested, and based on your code, to help you) but hopefully you can see where  I am going

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, i need to highlight only the matched text. How can i do that ?

Comment: find / replace.. in the each loop try `$(this).text = $(this).text.replace(keyword, "<b>" + keyword + "</b>");`

Comment: it's something like that.. you might have to replace inside the `.html()` rather than the `.text()`