# Javascript: document.execCommand compatibility on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, execcommand

I using some simple command like:

```
document.execCommand('bold',false,null)

document.execCommand('italic',false,null)
```

They are working fine with desktop browsers.

So i just want to know that are they compatible with mobile(Android,iOS) browsers also?

is there any drawback of using these command while developing a text editor?

I am unable to find a latest full compatibility matrices. I also visited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817441/javascript-document-execcommand-cross-browser) but unable to find complete information.

Answer (score 2):

You can know by queryCommandEnabled(). For example, if queryCommandEnabled('bold') returns true, it can use execCommand('bold').

Comment: @IE gave false on `bold` & `italic` ,so does the Firefox and chrome,so what does that means ? ,by the way +1 for good info.