# Copy, Cut and Paste text within a WYSIWYG

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

I'm trying to build a `WYSIWYG`, and I've three buttons: `copy`, `cut` and `paste`.

I tried this script for each one of them, but it didn't worked.

This is my script :

```
//Copy
document.getElementById('copy').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.execCommand('copy', false, null);
}, false);

//Cut
document.getElementById('cut').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.execCommand('cut', false, null);
}, false);

//Paste
document.getElementById('paste').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.execCommand('paste', false, null);
}, false);
```

In `Google chrome`, `Internet Explorer 11`, `Safari` and `Opera` no one of them has worked, and I don't get anything in the console.

In `Mozilla Firefox` I get this message :

```
Error: Permission denied for <file://> to get property Clipboard.cutcopy
document.execCommand('cut', false, null);
```

The same thing for `copy` and `paste`.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Check this link out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817441/javascript-document-execcommand-cross-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with JavaScript alone. You you have to depend on flash for this. Checkout [zeroclipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard). It might shed some hope :)

Comment: You can most definitely do this **without** flash in many modern browsers.

Comment: Could you please list some `modern browsers`? Even I am curious to know how would it be possible without permissions.