# how to underline selected text in web view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, underline

I use the code to load a request

```
[self.webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.wezeit.com/contentClient.php?postId=76949"]]];
```

and i use the code below to underline the text

```
- (void)note:(id)sender{
     NSString *result = [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand(\"Underline\")"];
     NSLog(@"result %@",result);
}
```

but it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Maybe your javascript was executed (and failed because it couldn't find the element to underline) before your webpage finished loading the content. I think UIWebView has a callback method `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` ( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidFinishLoad: ) for when it finished loading the page, maybe execute your javascript there.

Comment: hi, I confirm the web view finished loaded. because the note method above,is my custom uimenuitem handler.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps but someone mentions that the function call should looks like `document.execCommand(command, uiBool, argument)` maybe you're missing the other two parameters. Explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817441/javascript-document-execcommand-cross-browser  Perhaps you also need to do: `document.getElementById("whateverID").document.execCommand('underline', false, null);`

Comment: this help me out, code like below ` [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.contentEditable ='true';"
                        " document.execCommand(\"Underline\");"
                        "document.body.contentEditable ='false';"];`
but it shows a bottom bar that i don't need it ,how can hide it?